# Is there any way to search through encrypted data in firebase firestore?

Tags: firebase, react-native, encryption, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a react native app and using firebase firestore as a centralized database. Before placing user data on firestore I am encrypting the data using crypto js. Now I want to search through the database the problem is that the data is encrypted and when I try to encrypt the same data again crypto js creates different encrypting data. Is there any way possible to search through the encrypting data in firebase without loading the data in the mobile app and then decrypting it?

Comment: You can search encrypted values by also encrypting the search term. If the library you use generates a different encryption based on the same input, you'll want to configure it to give a stable output, or find a library that already does that. If you need help with that, update your question to show how you encrypt both the data, and the search term.

Comment: I am using the CryptoJS AES encrypting algorithm and it gives different results every time for the same input. Can you suggest me encrypting algorithm that can give me same result for same input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore does not support searching encrypted data.  If you encrypt it on the way in, you will have to decrypt it on the way out before you can know anything about the data you've stored.

Comment: So what should I do in this case? I am new to using the encrypting algorithm and I have no experience with them. I am using the CryptoJS AES encrypting algorithm currently.